Adding Header for Button in tree view Odoo 16/17
I am using Odoo 17.
I have added icons in tree view to perform some actions and i want to show header / label to these buttons.

I have tried a link for this and exactly I want the same in my case but didn't worked for me. Here is the link.

I also read and follow the instructions in this post but it does not working.
Looks like there is no _renderHeaderCell method.


The js framework has changed a lot and instead of trying to migrate code from v14 to v17, it will be easier to alter the web.ListRenderer template and append a title inside the header tag used for the button group.
Example:
<t t-inherit="web.ListRenderer" t-inherit-mode="extension">
    <th t-else="" position="inside">
        <t t-esc="column.buttons[0].title"/>
    </th>
</t>

You will need to add the file under the assets entry in the manifest
'assets': {
    "web.assets_backend": {
        'MODULE_NAME/static/src/xml/web_list_renderer.xml',           
    },
},


it still does not working :<<

You need to set the title attribute on the button

I think it is not a problem, I set a const variable to test like t-esc="Column Header", but it still does not work

Oh, I realized I misunderstood variables and values. It worked, thank you very much. <3
